# How do I get the value in an enum for a particular name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

Basically I'm writing my own version of a 'RoleProvider' and 'AuthorizeAttribute'.  I've got an Enum (as a bit field) with a list of all possible roles:

```
namespace myProject.Global
{
    [Flags]
    enum Roles
    {
        Viewer = 1,
        User = 2,
        Admin = 4,
        Superadmin = 8
    }
}
```

My AuthorizeAttribute works similarly to the existing one.  In my logic, I loop through each 'Authorized' role and check to see if the user belongs to it.  *_rolesSplit* is an array of the roles provided in the AuthorizeAttribute for a particular action.  *httpContext.Session["Roles"]* is an integer representing the user's roles.

```
 foreach (string roleName in _rolesSplit)
{
    if ((httpContext.Session["Roles"] & myProject.Global.Roles[roleName]) == myProject.Global.Roles[roleName]) return true;
}

return false;
```

This is the part I can't get working: *APICText.Global.Roles[roleName]*.  I'm new to .NET development so I'm not sure how to make this work.  I basically need to pass something the role name and get the associated value back.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx).

Try something like this...

```
foreach (string roleName in _rolesSplit)
{
    if (httpContext.Session["Roles"] & (Roles)Enum.Parse(typeof(Roles), roleName) == (Roles)Enum.Parse(typeof(Roles), roleName)) return true;
}
```

or this...

```
foreach (string roleName in _rolesSplit)
{
    Roles role = (Roles)Enum.Parse(typeof(Roles), roleName);
    if (httpContext.Session["Roles"] & role == role) return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to get this code working, although another bug in my code is preventing me from testing it right now.

Coming from PHP, the idea of strongly-typed objects/variables is still kinda new to me, definitely has major advantages when you know how to use it =]

Thanks again, I really appreciate it!!